# url cyrillic encoding issue (with webbrowser control)

Tags: c#, .net, string, url, webbrowser-control

I use C# web browser to send request. But url includes cyrillics symbols, and I use proxy so I need to encode the url.

The origin url: `http://mysite.com/info?q=москва+дизайн`

I need  `http://mysite.com/info?q=%E4%E8%E7%E0%E9%ED+%EC%EE%F1%EA%E2%E0`

What C# functions exist to make that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode().  Its default encoding is utf-8, yours look like Windows code page 1251 with the words reversed.  I suppose you ought to pass Encoding.Default.  The closest match is:

```
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
var url = "http://mysite.com/info?q=" + 
          System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("москва+дизайн", enc);
```

Which produces:

```
"http://mysite.com/info?q=%ec%ee%f1%ea%e2%e0%2b%e4%e8%e7%e0%e9%ed"
```