# Cyrillic symbols in HttpClient POST request for upload filename

Tags: c#, httprequest

In one of my .NET applications I've go a method which uploads file to the site via **HttpClient**. Here is implementation

```
        using (var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true
        })
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = requestAddress;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {

                    var streamContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(fileData));

                    streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse("form-data");
                    streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("name", "contentFile"));
                    streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("filename", "\"" + fileName + "\""));
                    streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);

                    content.Add(streamContent);

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/Files/UploadFile", content);


                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Method work fine. But when I pass Cyrillic symbols in **fileName** property generated post request filename has corrupted symbols like **????1.docx** for exmaple where **?** replaces the Cyrillic symbol. Is there any way to send Cyrillic symbols without corruption?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196258/url-cyrillic-encoding-issue-with-webbrowser-control)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `filename` is very limited on what you can do in terms of code page. I guess it only supports ASCII (not 100% sure). There is a better header you can use called `filename*` which is bit hard to google for since google will just remove the `*` and you get all the ordinary `filename` back.

Long story short you need to use this:

```
$"filename*=UTF-8''{fileName}"
```

You also might need to do some encoding of filename with regard to space, etc. You can google a bit more on that + check this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543584/unicode-in-content-disposition-header).

P.S. Some older browsers might not like it, you need to check your requirements.